# C# regex URL Substitution

Tags: regex

Can you please provide regular expression in c#?

I am trying to change the domains in URLs to one domain and bring the files to level one in the path

#### Example:

```
http://goo.com/working/1.html
http://boo.com/kit/jo.png
```

Would become:

```
http://mysit1e.com/1.html 
http://mysit1e.com/jo.png
```

Comment: That sounds great! Do you have any questions? Also, do you have any code so that, when you post a question, we can reference it and see that you've tried something?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and ask a specific question about what you are having trouble with. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We are here to help you learn, not do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String inputUrls  = "http://goo.com/working/1.html http:/boo.com/kit/jo.png";
String newBaseUrl = "http:/mysit1e.com/"
String rplReg     =@"http.*?(?=[^/\s]+?(\s+|$))"
String outUrls    = Regex.Replace(inputUrls,rplReg,newBaseUrl);
```

This output should be

```
http:/mysit1e.com/1.html http:/mysit1e.com/jo.png
```

---

**Regex Explanation**

```
http     # Only works for http headers
.*?      # Rest of the base url
(?=      # Positive Lookahead(This is not selected for replacement) Only match the URL if it is followed by this condition
[^\s/]+? # Condition for the last leg shouldnt have `/` or a space `\s`
(\s+|$)  # last leg should be followed by either space `\s+` or end of string.
)        # End of Positive Lookahead
```

Last but not the least don't forget the `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`